# Centering a bootstrap grid on mobile

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to center a 2×3 grid of images & text and although it works on desktop, it has a seemingly weird offset on mobile. For example, here's how it looks on desktop:

[image: Desktop View]

and here's the layout on mobile:

[image: Mobile View]

The HTML section is defined as follows:

```
<div class="row" id="selected-works-section">
    <h1>Selected Works</h1>

    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div id="selected-works-grid" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div
            class="selected-works-grid-item col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"
          >
            <img
              src="/assets/images/belden_suites.jpg"
              alt="belden suites"
              class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block"
            />
            <div class="selected-works-grid-item-text col-lg-8 offset-xl-2">
              <h6>BELDEN SUITES</h6>
              <p>Creative direction and execution, 2015</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div
            class="selected-works-grid-item col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"
          >
            <img
              src="/assets/images/camies_kitchen.jpg"
              alt="camie's kitchen"
              class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block"
            />
            <div class="selected-works-grid-item-text col-lg-8 offset-xl-2">
              <h6>CAMIE'S KITCHEN</h6>
              <p>Concept and design, 2018</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div
            class="selected-works-grid-item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"
          >
            <img
              src="/assets/images/fairhill_hall.jpg"
              alt="fairhill hall"
              class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block"
            />
            <div class="selected-works-grid-item-text col-lg-8 offset-xl-2">
              <h6>FAIRHILL HALL</h6>
              <p>Concept and rendering, 2013</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div
            class="selected-works-grid-item col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"
          >
            <img
              src="/assets/images/gaels_restaurant.jpg"
              alt="gael's restaurant"
              class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block"
            />
            <div class="selected-works-grid-item-text col-lg-8 offset-xl-2">
              <h6>GAEL'S RESTAURANT</h6>
              <p>Concept, rendering and execution, 2015</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div
            class="selected-works-grid-item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"
          >
            <img
              src="/assets/images/guajardo_residence.jpg"
              alt="guajardo residence"
              class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block"
            />
            <div class="selected-works-grid-item-text col-lg-8 offset-xl-2">
              <h6>GUAJARDO RESIDENCE</h6>
              <p>Concept, rendering and execution, 2025</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div
            class="selected-works-grid-item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"
          >
            <img
              src="/assets/images/newark_residence.jpg"
              alt="newark residence"
              class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block"
            />
            <div class="selected-works-grid-item-text col-lg-8 offset-xl-2">
              <h6>NEWARK RESIDENCE</h6>
              <p>Concept, rendering and execution, 2020</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and here's the custom css code:

```
/* selected works section */

.selected-works-grid-item > img {
  max-width: 350px;
  max-height: 200px;
}

.selected-works-grid-item-text > h6 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

What could be causing this offset on mobile? I tried various combinations of `col-md-X` values and using the `mx-auto` & `d-block` classes without `img-fluid` but to no avail.

Comment: Your images are linked locally, and I can't duplicate the issue. Could you provide a working model on jsfiddle.net or a like site?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the problem, but I see that for the col-sm class, you are putting three div with the class col-sm-12 in the same row. Each row is supposed to have a total sum 12 for columns, that way it has 36.

Comment: @scatolone It's totally fine to have >12 per `row`. They are designed to wrap seamlessly.

Comment: In fact I would suggest putting all 6 items into the same `row` here, because currently your `md` breakpoint will have 2-1-2-1 items instead of 2-2-2 items. (But I don't think this is related to the mobile offset.)

Comment: I tried but I was not able to reproduce the issue. What tool are you using to display the mobile layout? Maybe that browser has a default stylesheet interfering with Bootstrap classes

Comment: It's difficult to provide a solution without checking CSS using inspect elements for smaller screen size. But looks like some extra padding coming on the left side from some CSS. I would suggest you to create a codepen and share the link for a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

**d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center** is used to center elements.

```css
 /* selected works section */

  .selected-works-grid-item > img {
    max-width: 350px;
    max-height: 200px;
  }

  .selected-works-grid-item-text > h6 {
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-weight: bolder;
  }
```

```html
<link
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
  integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
<script
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>

<div class="container-fluid" id="selected-works-section">
  <h1>Selected Works</h1>

  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div id="selected-works-grid" class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div
          class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center selected-works-grid-item col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"
        >
          <img
            src="/assets/images/belden_suites.jpg"
            alt="belden suites"
            class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block"
          />
          <div
            class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center selected-works-grid-item-text col-lg-8 offset-xl-2"
          >
            <h6>BELDEN SUITES</h6>
            <p>Creative direction and execution, 2015</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div
          class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center selected-works-grid-item col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"
        >
          <img
            src="/assets/images/camies_kitchen.jpg"
            alt="camies kitchen"
            class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block"
          />
          <div
            class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center selected-works-grid-item-text col-lg-8 offset-xl-2"
          >
            <h6>CAMIE'S KITCHEN</h6>
            <p>Concept and design, 2018</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div
          class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center selected-works-grid-item col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"
        >
          <img
            src="/assets/images/fairhill_hall.jpg"
            alt="fairhill hall"
            class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block"
          />
          <div
            class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center selected-works-grid-item-text col-lg-8 offset-xl-2"
          >
            <h6>FAIRHILL HALL</h6>
            <p>Concept and rendering, 2013</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div
          class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center selected-works-grid-item col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"
        >
          <img
            src="/assets/images/gaels_restaurant.jpg"
            alt="gael's restaurant"
            class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block"
          />
          <div
            class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center selected-works-grid-item-text col-lg-8 offset-xl-2"
          >
            <h6>GAEL'S RESTAURANT</h6>
            <p>Concept, rendering and execution, 2015</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div
          class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center selected-works-grid-item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"
        >
          <img
            src="/assets/images/guajardo_residence.jpg"
            alt="guajardo residence"
            class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block"
          />
          <div
            class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center selected-works-grid-item-text col-lg-8 offset-xl-2"
          >
            <h6>GUAJARDO RESIDENCE</h6>
            <p>Concept, rendering and execution, 2025</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div
          class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center selected-works-grid-item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"
        >
          <img
            src="/assets/images/newark_residence.jpg"
            alt="newark residence"
            class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block"
          />
          <div
            class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center selected-works-grid-item-text col-lg-8 offset-xl-2"
          >
            <h6>NEWARK RESIDENCE</h6>
            <p>Concept, rendering and execution, 2020</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like the other answers and comments, I was not able to duplicate the offset on mobile. It’s best to use StackOverflow’s code snippet function to include a working example of your code with the problem, rather than using a screen capture.

Your screen capture seems to show a horizontal scrollbar, indicating your page is wider than the viewport. That may be because you don’t have your first row inside a container.

You’re defining your image sizes using pixels, but Bootstrap uses percentages. It may be better to use the img-fluid class, rather than overriding those values.

For your item text, you’re defining a column inside of a column with no containing row div.  I don’t think that’s causing the mobile offset problem, but it might be good to add a row div.

As @tdy pointed out, having all six columns in one row would work nicely.

```css
.selected-works-grid-item-text>h6 {
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="selected-works-section">
        <h1>Selected Works</h1>

        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div id="selected-works-grid" class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="selected-works-grid-item col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/700x400/870000/fff.png&text=Belden+Suites" alt="Belden Suites" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" width="350" height="200">
                        <div class="selected-works-grid-item-text col-10 offset-1 col-sm-8 offset-sm-2 col-md-10 offset-md-1 col-lg-8 offset-lg-2">
                            <h6>BELDEN SUITES</h6>
                            <p>Creative direction and execution, 2015</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="selected-works-grid-item col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/700x400/877100/fff.png&text=Camie's+Kitchen" alt="Camie's Kitchen" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" width="350" height="200">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="selected-works-grid-item-text col-10 offset-1 col-sm-8 offset-sm-2 col-md-10 offset-md-1 col-lg-8 offset-lg-2">
                                <h6>CAMIE'S KITCHEN</h6>
                                <p>Concept and design, 2018</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="selected-works-grid-item col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/700x400/2D8700/fff.png&text=Fairhill+Hall" alt="Fairhill Hall" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" width="350" height="200">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="selected-works-grid-item-text col-10 offset-1 col-sm-8 offset-sm-2 col-md-10 offset-md-1 col-lg-8 offset-lg-2">
                                <h6>FAIRHILL HALL</h6>
                                <p>Concept and rendering, 2013</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="selected-works-grid-item col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/700x400/008744/fff.png&text=Gael's+Restaurant" alt="Gael's Restaurant" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" width="350" height="200">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="selected-works-grid-item-text col-10 offset-1 col-sm-8 offset-sm-2 col-md-10 offset-md-1 col-lg-8 offset-lg-2">
                                <h6>GAEL'S RESTAURANT</h6>
                                <p>Concept, rendering and execution, 2015</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="selected-works-grid-item col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/700x400/005A87/fff.png&text=Guarjardo+Residence" alt="Guajardo Residence" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" width="350" height="200">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="selected-works-grid-item-text col-10 offset-1 col-sm-8 offset-sm-2 col-md-10 offset-md-1 col-lg-8 offset-lg-2">
                                <h6>GUAJARDO RESIDENCE</h6>
                                <p>Concept, rendering and execution, 2025</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="selected-works-grid-item col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/700x400/170087/fff.png&text=Newark+Residence" alt="Newark Residence" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" width="350" height="200">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="selected-works-grid-item-text col-10 offset-1 col-sm-8 offset-sm-2 col-md-10 offset-md-1 col-lg-8 offset-lg-2">
                                <h6>NEWARK RESIDENCE</h6>
                                <p>Concept, rendering and execution, 2020</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I stayed with your 350px wide image size, so the images won’t fill the columns. You could use a larger image (e.g. 700px wide), which would fill the column widths. If you do that, you might want to change the offset value for the item-text.